# AWSSDK.SES - need SES and cant use AWSDK due to name clash

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I have a .net project and had to upgrade AWSSDK to AWSDK.Core and AWSSDK.S3/AWSSDK.SQS. We used to use the older AWSSDK but need the newer libraries to support FIFO queues. Only issue is that we use SES and there is no equiveleant AWSSDK.SES that I can see, I cant reference both AWSSDK and the core libraries as I get ambiguous references - anyone else had this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called AWSSDK.SimpleEmail
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.SimpleEmail/

It lists AWSSDK.Core as a dependency.